# mysql - how to copy table and keep same keys and encoding?

Tags: php, mysql, replication

Just wrote a short script of copying all my tables into another local database. was quite easy but after checking it I found that the keys are gone and also the encoding for text fields are set to some default encoding.

How can I use my script and have the same keys and same encoding duplicated after copying, but not manually define for each table. I have to get this done automatically.

my code is pretty straight forward:

```
$first_db = 'first_db';
$second_db = 'second_db';


$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $first_db");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $current_table = $row["Tables_in_$first_db"];
    $result2 = mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $second_db.$table_name");
    $result2 = mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $second_db.$table_name SELECT * FROM $first_db.$current_table");
}
```

I think I should use ALTER TABLE, but can it find and define the keys and encoding automatically ?

Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the output from `mysqldump`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried copying the table first then populate the data aftewards?

`create table second_db.table_name like first_db.table_name`;

And then start populating the data afterwards.

`insert into second_db.table_name select * from first_db.table_name`;

Comment: the whole script can be found in an answer to a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997101/can-you-use-a-mysql-query-to-completely-create-a-copy-of-the-database/6046847#6046847

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CREATE TABLE foo LIKE bar` and an [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html says:

> Use LIKE to create an empty table based on the definition of another table, including any column attributes and indexes defined in the original table:
>
> `CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;`
>
> The copy is created using the same version of the table storage format as the original table. The SELECT privilege is required on the original table.
>
> LIKE works only for base tables, not for views.
>
> `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or any foreign key definitions.