# Can you use a MySQL Query to Completely Create a Copy of the Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a LIVE version of a MySQL database with 5 tables and a TEST version.

I am continually using phpMyAdmin to make a copy of each table in the LIVE version to the TEST version.

Does anyone have the mysql query statement to make a complete copy of a database? The query string would need to account for structure, data, auto increment values, and any other things associated with the tables that need to be copied.

Thanks.

Comment: From the comments below, it is looking like this cannot be easily done in a PHP / mysql query statement from the browser address bar.

Comment: Still does not look like this is do-able in a PHP script that can be run from the browser address bar.

Comment: Another comment... the reason I want to take a snapshot copy of the LIVE db to a TEST db is that when I need to troubleshoot an issue or implement expanded code, I want to test it out before I implement live. So I want top be able to grab an up-to-date DB at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of research, googling, and reading through everyone's comments herein, I produced the following script -- which I now run from the browser address bar. Tested it and it does exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks for everyone's help.

```
<?php
function duplicateTables($sourceDB=NULL, $targetDB=NULL) {
    $link = mysql_connect('{server}', '{username}', '{password}') or die(mysql_error()); // connect to database
    $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $sourceDB) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query('CREATE TABLE `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '` LIKE `' . $sourceDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '` SELECT * FROM `' . $sourceDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query('OPTIMIZE TABLE `' . $targetDB . '`.`' . $row[0] . '`') or die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);
} // end duplicateTables()
duplicateTables('liveDB', 'testDB');
?>
```

Comment: Foreign key doesn't create!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your access to the server. I suggest using straight `mysql` and `mysqldump` commands. That's all phpMyAdmin is doing under the hood.

Comment: But doesn't mysqldump require you to telnet into the server and run it from the command line? I have done it that way before and it ends up being just as manually intensive as using phpMyAdmin. I was hoping to have a script that I could launch from the browser address bar to do it more quickly.

Comment: Theoretically you could put these commands in a web accessible PHP script using `exec()`. However, I don't recommend that per security.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I tried doing some other tricky things in my apps using exec() and I could never ever get anything to work with exec()...have many stackoverflow threads on that one. So I gave up with exec() -- probably a good thing to do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Reference material for Mysqldump.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: I have my own set of documented notes and settings to follow using mysqldump from the command line. I have done it that way numerous times. Was hoping to do it in a PHP Script. Unless, mysqldump can be run through PHP...

Comment: you can run mysqldump via php using one of the [system program execution functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php)

Comment: Thanks @Xaade. See my comment to Jason below.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3498-PHP-Dump-a-MySQL-database-in-a-backup-file.html) for that, I didn't test it yet.

From it's description:

```
This class can be used to backup a MySQL database.

It queries a database and generates a list of SQL statements that can be used later to restore the database **tables structure** and their contents.
```

I guess this what you need.

Comment: I do not need a "backup" routine. I need a script that takes an entire database and duplicates it - as is, with all its data, structures and settings at the push of a button. My www.domain.com site uses the LIVE db at all times. My test.domain.com sites uses the TEST db at all times. So what I want to do is run duplicate_that_entire_db_as_is.php from my browser address bar. I already use phpMyAdmin to manually duplicate each table everytime I use test.domain.com. I am just trying to eliminate the tediousness of phpmyadmin

Comment: @Dr. Live db clone may cause your script finish before it can complete the copy process, plus it may hang browser(I run in like this situation), so better practice is to backup database in file then restore it in another database, finally delete the backup file if it has sensitive information(user email's, password's, etc...).

Comment: Which is somehow what phpMyAdmin is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you can use simple bash script to backup whole database.

```
######### SNIP BEGIN ########## 
## Copy from here ############# 
#!/bin/bash 
# to use the script do following: 
# sh   backup.sh DBNAME | sh 
# where DBNAME is database name from alma016 
# ex Backuping mydb data: 
# sh  backup.sh mydb hostname username pass| sh 
echo "#sh  backup.sh mydb hostname username pass| sh" 
DB=$1
host=$2
user=$3
pass=$4 
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y") 
FILE="$DB.backup.$NOW.gz" 
# rest of script 
#dump command: 
cmd="mysqldump -h $host -u$user -p$pass  $DB | gzip -9 > $FILE"
echo $cmd 
############ END SNIP ###########
```

EDIT

If you like to clone backuped database just edit the dump and change the database name then:

```
      tar xzf yourdump.tar.gz| mysql -uusername -ppass
```

cheers Arman.

Comment: Just to be clear @Arman, the "backed-up" database needs to be immediately accessible as my test database. So by following your solution, would my PHP scripts work against the "backed-up" database? It seems you are producing a compressed (zipped) copy. That is not the nature of my post.

Comment: you can restore it to another database...it willbe exactly same as your backup one.

Comment: But again if you need to copy the table you can use statement create table netab like livetab; this will create indexss as well.

Comment: @Arman, I am looking for something that I can run from the browser address bar to handle it all. Is that do-able? If, so what does it look like?

Comment: Use simple php script which calls the bash script eg: sysexec("backup.sh").where bash script eg pipes the output to mysql.

Comment: I have never had any luck with exec() or sysexec(). I posted a few threads on Stackoverflow but never got it to work on my server. But Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I dont know what do you mean, just try to see if this snippet is working?:    `function getFiles($fdir) {
    $cmd = "/bin/ls -d $fdir*/*";
    $out = "";
    $output = "";
    $out = exec($cmd, $output);
    echo $cmd."<br>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($output as $o) {
        echo "<li>" . $o . "</li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}`

Answer (score 0):

Well in script form, you could try using

[`CREATE TABLE ... LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) syntax, iterating through a list of tables, which you can get from [`SHOW TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html).

Only problem is that does not recreate indexes or foreign keys natively.  So you would have to list them and create them as well.  Then a few [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) calls to get the data in.

If your schema never changes, only the data.  Then create a script that replicates the table structure and then just do the `INSERT ... SELECT` business in a transaction.

Failing that, `mysqldump` as the others say is pretty easy to get working from a script.  I have a daily firing cron job that dumps all manner of databases from my datacenter servers, connects via FTPS to my location and sends all the dumps across.  It can be done, quite effectively.  Obviously you have to make sure such facilities are locked down, but again, not overly hard.

---

**As per code request**

The code is proprietary, but I'll show you the critical section that you need.  This is from in the middle of a `foreach` loop, hence the `continue` statements and the `$c..` prefixed variables (I use that to indicate *current* loop (or instance) variables).  The `echo` commands could be whatever you want, this is a `cron` script, so echoing current status was appropriate.  The `flush()` lines are helpful for when you run the script from the browser, as the output will be sent up to that point, so the browser results fill as it runs, rather than all turning up at the end.  The `ftp_fput()` line is obviously down to my situation of uploading the dump somewhere and uploads directly from the pipe - you could use another process open to pipe the output in to a `mysql` process to replicate the database.  Providing suitable amendments where made.

```
$cDumpCmd = $mysqlDumpPath . ' -h' . $dbServer . ' -u' . escapeshellarg($cDBUser) . ' -p' . escapeshellarg($cDBPassword) . ' ' . $cDatabase . (!empty($dumpCommandOptions) ? ' ' . $dumpCommandOptions : '');

$cPipeDesc = array(0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
                   1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
                   2 => array('pipe', 'w'));
$cPipes = array();

$cStartTime = microtime(true);

$cDumpProc = proc_open($cDumpCmd, $cPipeDesc, $cPipes, '/tmp', array());

if (!is_resource($cDumpProc)) {
    echo "failed.\n";
    continue;
} else {
    echo "success.\n";
}

echo "DB: " . $cDatabase . " - Uploading Database...";

flush();

$cUploadResult = ftp_fput($ftpConn, $dbFileName, $cPipes[1], FTP_BINARY);

$cStopTime = microtime(true);

if ($cUploadResult) {
    echo "success (" . round($cStopTime - $cStartTime, 3) . " seconds).\n";
    $databaseCount++;
} else {
    echo "failed.\n";
    continue;
}

$cErrorOutput = stream_get_contents($cPipes[2]);

foreach ($cPipes as $cFHandle) {
    fclose($cFHandle);
}

$cDumpStatus = proc_close($cDumpProc);

if ($cDumpStatus != 0) {
    echo "DB: " . $cDatabase . " - Dump process caused an error:\n";
    echo $cErrorOutput . "\n";
    continue;
}

flush();
```

Comment: what does it look like? Are you able to share anything on how it looks? I know how to launch crontab jobs, but I need something that allows me to run it from the browser address bar, as I need it.

Comment: @Dr. DOT: Added example code, with an explanation, see if that helps you.  It is part of the script I run via `cron` - the location it is in is protected via usual Basic authentication means and the script has no user interaction, so can not be influenced and doesn't output anything of high security other than database names and is not linked to anywhere, so is unlikely to be found at any rate.  Worst case scenario, someone could request the daily backup twice, and it detects that anyhow and does not proceed.

Comment: I'll look at it and see if I can get it to work for me -- thanks.  FYI, I want to be able to run it at anytime so I don't want any multiple execution detection. Thanks again.

Comment: @Dr. DOT: That particular piece of code does not have the multiple execution detection within it, so not to worry about that.  The bits of particular interest to you would be the process handling `proc_open()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux or mac, here is a single line to clone a database.

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hsample.host --single-transaction --quick test | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hqa.sample.host --database=test
```

The 'advantage' here is that it will lock the database while its making a copy.
That means you end up with a consistent copy.
It also means your production database will be tied up for the duration of the copy which generally isn't a good thing.

Without locks or transactions, if something is writing to the database while you're making a copy, you could end up with orphaned data in your copy.

To get a good copy without impacting production, you should create a slave on another server.
The slave is updated in real time.
You can run the same command on the slave without impacting production.